# „Ich ohne dich [bin/ist] wie ein Sänger ohne Lied?“

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-usage

> Ich ohne dich ____ wie ein Sänger ohne Lied.

#### English

Should it be *bin* or *ist?* I have been told that it should be *ist,* while *bin* agrees with the subject *ich.*

#### Deutsch

Sollte es *bin* oder *ist* sein? Mir wurde mitgeteilt, dass es *ist* sein sollte, aber *bin* passt zum Subjekt *ich.*

Comment: Ist das aus einem Übungsbuch, wo jemand die Lücke gesetzt hat, oder hast Du die Lücke nach bestem Wissen da gesetzt, wo Du meinst, dass das Verb hingehört? "Ich *bin* ohne Dich wie ein Sänger ohne Lied" wäre der übliche Ausdruck. Da Sänger aber gerne von Sängern singen könnte es Poesie sein - dann würde ich die Antworten äüös und Jans für richtig halten.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If "Ich ohne dich" is meant as description of a state (*Der Zustand*), "ist" is right.

Otherwise, you rather said "Ich bin ohne dich wie ein Sänger ohne Lied", and *bin* belongs to *Ich* then.

Comment: although I'm more used to this one: "Ich ohne dich - das ist wie ein Sänger ohne Lied." which makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

> … aber *bin* passt zum Subjekt *ich.*

Und hier bist du gestolpert. So, wie der Satz dasteht, ist das Subjekt nicht *ich*. *Ich* kann gar nicht alleine das Subjekt sein, denn wenn das Subjekt am Satzanfang steht, muss in einem normalen Satz direkt das Verb folgen. Daher äüös Variante:

> *Ich bin* ohne dich wie ein Sänger ohne Lied.

Im gefragten Satz steht aber zwischen *ich* und der Lücke für das Verb noch *ohne dich.* Es wäre prinzipiell möglich (ganz im Rammstein’schen Sinne?), *ohne dich* als Satzglied zu verstehen. Dann ergibt sich aber die gleiche Problematik: Vor dem finiten Verb steht nur ein Satzglied, also entweder *ich* oder *ohne dich.* Erlaubt wäre also die folgende Variante, die ebenfalls *bin* verlangen würde, denn *ich* bleibt in ihr das Subjekt:

> *Ohne dich* bin ich wie ein Sänger ohne Lied.

Wie in dieser Antwort schon ein paar Mal angeklungen ist, sind die bisherigen Interpretationen nicht valide, wenn *ich ohne dich* gemeinsam vor dem Verb steht. In diesem Fall muss es sich bei *ich ohne dich* um *ein* Satzglied handeln – und da dahinter nur noch das beschreibende »wie ein Sänger ohne Lied« kommt, spricht alles dafür, dass *ich ohne dich* **zusammen** das Subjekt ist. *Ich ohne dich* ist aber nicht mehr *ich,* also nicht mehr das Personalpronomen der ersten Person Singular. Folglich ist auch die Verbform nicht mehr in der ersten Person Singular; es muss sich um die dritte Person handeln. Die Lücke füllen kann also nur *ist:*

> *Ich ohne dich* **ist** wie ein Sänger ohne Lied.

Comment: Stölpern ist aber kein richtiges Verb. Ist das Mundart? Ein Scherz? Wieso nicht *gestolpert*? Gegenüber Anfängern finde ich scherzhafte Laxheiten im Sprach-Q&A unangemessen - Ausnahmen wären solche, die sich aus dem Thema ergeben und jedermann verständlich sind. Deine bisherigen Texte lassen mich aber nicht vermuten, dass es Dir nur einfach unterlaufen ist, weswegen ich es nicht stillschweigend korrigieren will.

Comment: @userunknown Ich habe die Diskussion gerade mit DHMO und Loong in den Chats von Chemie.SE geführt. So, wie ich das spreche, hat das Verb einen Umlaut, aber du hast recht: ich finde das nirgends schriftlich festgehalten. Ich vermute Mundart, bin mir aber auch nicht sicher.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you should omit the "ohne dich," (which could be set off by parentheses), from consideration in the phrase. Then you should use the first person singular, "bin."

Ich (ohne dich) **bin** wie ein Sänger ohne Lied.

There is a (rare) exception in literary usage, if you treat "ich ohne dich" as a single unit, then this "unit" would be in the third person, and you would use "ist". I would represent this with hyphens as:

Ich-ohne-dich **ist** wie ein Sänger ohne Lied.

This "unit" would be in contrast to "ich-mit-dir."